# Intersection point between a line and a plane?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

So we have a line, let's called it line $L$, that passes through $(2,−2,1)$ and $(−4,1,−3)$.

We also have a plane, let's call it $V$, that is given by the equation $3x + 4y + 4z = -42$.

How can I now determine the intersection point between the line and the equation?

Comment: Do you know how to parametrize the line $L$? Once that's accomplished, the intersection is found from straightforward algebra.

Answer (score 0):

A vector parallel to the line is given by $\vec{v}=\vec{PQ}=\langle-6,3,-4\rangle$, so

you can write the line in parametric form as $x=2-6t, y=-2+3t, z=1-4t$.

Now substitute these expressions into the equation of the plane and solve for t.